# Oracle Service Bus Proxy Service Scheduler

Tags: scheduler, osb, oracle-service-bus

I need to create a proxy service scheduler that receive messages of the queue after 5 minutes. like queue produce message either a single or multiple but proxy receieve that messages after interval of every 5 minutes. how can i achieve this only using oracle service bus ... 
Kindly help me for this

Answer (score 0):

OSB do not provide Scheduler capabilities out of the box. You can do either of the following:

1. For JMS Queue put infinite retries by not setting retry limit and set retry interval as 5 minutes.
2. Create a scheduler. Check this post for the same: http://blogs.oracle.com/jamesbayer/entry/weblogic_scheduling_a_polling

Answer (score 0):

*Answer left for reference only, messages shouldn't be a subject to complex computed selections in this way, some value comparison and pattern matching only.*

To fetch only old enough messages from queue,

- not modifying queue or messages
- not introducing any new brokers between queue and consumer
- not prematurely consuming messages

, use *Message Selector* field of *OSB Proxy* on *JMS Transport* tab to set boolean expression (SQL 92) that checks that message's *JMSTimestamp* header is at least 5 minutes older than current time.

... and I wasn't successful to quickly produce valid message selector neither from timestamp nor JMSMessageID (it contains time in milis - 'ID:<465788.**1372152510324**.0>').

I guess somebody could still use it in some specific case.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Quartz scheduler APIs to create schedulers across domains.

Regards,
Sajeev

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether this works for you, but its working good for me. May be you can use this to do your needful.

Goto Transport Details of your Proxy Service, under **Advanced Options** tab, set the following fields.

**Polling Frequency** (Mention your frequency 300 sec(5 min))

**Physical Directory** (may be here you need to give your Queue path)